# Dúvida de como captar a animação do personagem no Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, animação

Estou tentando fazer um comando que ative uma animação quando eu aperta 2 teclas do keyboard e, quando eu parar de apertar uma delas, essa animação parasse. Por exemplo eu escolhi a tecla "w" + "leftShift", quando as duas estiverem pressionadas quero que inicie a  animação, "RUN". Quando eu parar de apertar "leftShift", quero que  inicie uma animação de andar "WALK", e por último quando eu parar de apertar  "w", eu quero que ele inicie uma animação de parado "IDDLE". Alguém poderia me ajudar? Aqui está o comando que estou tentado fazer funcionar:

```
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) + (Input.GetKey ("w"))) {
            animationController.PlayAnimation (AnimationStates.RUN);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Uitilize o operador `&&` ao invés de `+`,  caso seja apenas o `W` rode a animação de walk. E utilize o método `GetKeyDown()` para identificar uma tecla pressionada

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKey("w"))
{
    animationController.PlayAnimation(AnimationStates.RUN);
}
else if (Input.GetKey("w"))
{
    animationController.PlayAnimation(AnimationStates.WALK);
}
```

[Unity - Scripting API: KeyCode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html)

Comment: poise testei esse método deram certo o único problema que esta acontecendo e quando eu solto o "shift" mas continuo apertando o "w", ele continua fazendo a animação de correr, só quando eu solto o "w" e aperto novamente que ele faz a animação de andar.

Comment: Esse trecho está dentro do `Update()`?

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer usando um `if` dentro de outro:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift){
    if((Input.GetKey ("w"))){
        animationController.PlayAnimation (AnimationStates.RUN);
    }
}
```

ou então podes fazer com o `and` usando `$$`

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && (Input.GetKey ("w"))) {
   animationController.PlayAnimation (AnimationStates.RUN);
}
```

A função `Input.GetKey` devolve um boolean tens que usares operadores lógicos para o que pretende obter, e não podes somar booleans, `true + true` não existe.

Comment: poise testei esse método deram certo o único problema que esta acontecendo e quando eu solto o "shift" mas continuo apertando o "w", ele continua fazendo a animação de correr, só quando eu solto o "w" e aperto novamente que ele faz a animação de andar.

Comment: Normalmente é assim que os jogos funcionam mas se quiseres alterar isso é fazeres um caso para mudar a animação `if !(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && (Input.GetKey ("w")))` depois metendo o que queres lá dentro.

Answer (score 1):

Esse código talvez pode lhe ajudar:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKey("w"))
   {
     animationController.PlayAnimation(AnimationStates.RUN);
     if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.w))
        {
          animationController.PlayAnimation(AnimationStates.WALK);
        }
   }
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, mas desde o começo não eram  os comandos que estavam erados mais sim la no animator pois uma condição la estava invertida. ai resolvi o problema, mesmo assim obrigado pela sua atenção

Comment: Que bom que deu tudo certo!